# Failed to connect to center.conan.io

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I am trying to use this [github template](https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/cpp_starter_project) to set up a project. However, when trying to find dependencies, I obtain the following error message:

```
catch2/2.13.7: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
ERROR: Failed requirement 'catch2/2.13.7' from 'conanfile.py (CppStarterProject/0.1)'
ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='center.conan.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/ping (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))

Unable to connect to cci=https://center.conan.io
1. Make sure the remote is reachable or,
2. Disable it by using conan remote disable,
Then try again.
CMake Error at build/conan.cmake:631 (message):
  Conan install failed='1'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Conan.cmake:47 (conan_cmake_install)
  CMakeLists.txt:66 (run_conan)
```

When trying to ping center.conan.io It seems to be online and https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/center.conan.io?proto=https does say that it is up.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Conan seems to sometimes not update it's certificate authorities (probably if you've manually edited them). Make sure you are using the latest Conan version and delete `cacert.pem` from the .conan directory in your home folder, re-running Conan should then generate an updated cacert.pem with the latest authorities.

Comment: I tried to update conan via `pip install --user --upgrade conan` and I deleted the .conan folder but I still encounter the error. Also, I have not edited the certificate authorities. Maybe something other than conan related files that I need to modify ?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, i don't know how but I had 2 versions of conan living separately. Using the latest fixed the issue. Thanks!